# What is the most efficient method of displaying many components using the FlowLayout?

Tags: codenameone

I'm working on a form that shows many our company's products in a FlowLayout, but on some categories that hold many products, performance in scrolling is noticeably affected. I switched to a List so I could leverage the performance benefits of using a renderer, but now I'm not happy with the layout since there's a lot of wasted space, especially if the device is in landscape mode.

My next thought was to use a Table, which I believe also uses renderers to optimize the display of its data; but to mimic a FlowLayout, I'd need to get the preferred width of some placeholder component, then divide the container's width by that to get the number of columns, and then fill the model with that number of columns in mind. I'd also need to change all that if the device changes orientation.

Before I go down that rabbit hole, I'm wondering if I'm making things unnecessarily complicated for myself and if there's already something that I can use to achieve that goal. So to summarize, what would be the most efficient way to display data (that would be shown as buttons) sequentially from left to right, and top to bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `FlowLayout` for anything serious although I doubt its the reason for your performance issues, those probably relate to something else. There is a performance how do I video which is a bit old but mostly still relevant: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---improve-application-performance-or-track-down-performance-issues.html

In design terms flow layout is hugely problematic since the elements are not aligned properly thus producing a UI that doesn't look good when spanning multiple rows. I suggest using a grid layout which has a mode called auto fit. By using `setAutoFit(true)` on a grid of even 1x1 all the elements will take up all available space uniformly based on screen size and adapt with orientation changes.